# How to change button style on hover?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the font color background color on hover of the button text and the icon.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2em;
  color: #eff6f9;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Merriweather, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-shadow: none;
  transition: background-color 0.125s ease-in;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.button a {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
}

.shop:hover>span,
.shop:focus>span,
.shop:active>span {
  color: white;
}

a:focus,
.button a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="button" id="bu">
  <a class="shop" href="https://app.nmpl.store/">
    <span>Order Now</span>
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Currently When I hover over the button only the border changes first and then the text in between the button, I want to change the color and background of the entire button when I hover just on the border also.

[image]

pointer outside button

[image]

Pointer on edge of button

[image]

Pointer on text

Comment: I think your question would gain in clarity if you removed all those `.fa-w-18`-related lines in your css as they seem irrelevant (no item with this class in your html)

Comment: why don't you use a `<button>` instead of a `div`, also you could style simply using `a` tag

Comment: Stronger than ^: [please use `<button>` for buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML). There's literally no reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just changed a couple of things in your code:
HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="bu">
    <a class="shop button" href="https://app.nmpl.store/">
        Order Now <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
   background-color: black;
}

.button {
   background-color: white;
   border: 2px solid #FFF;
   border-radius: 35px;
   color: #000;
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: Merriweather, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 300;
   font-style: italic;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: bold;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   line-height: 1;
   text-decoration:none;
   padding: 20px 30px;
   text-shadow: none;
   transition: background-color 0.125s ease-in;
   margin-top: 3em;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: white;
    color: white;
}
```

Hope that helps you :)

Comment: So, in substance, you moved the `button` class from the `div` to the `a` and removed the `span` tag?

Comment: Basically yeah, the div could go too unless it's needed for other elements but I 
always find it much simpler styling the `a` as opposed to a `div` when there's no need for a div to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Really good example on why it's important to use the correct elements for the right job. Don't use divs where you don't need them.

Get rid of the div and use a simple link element that you style to look like your button.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Merriweather, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-shadow: none;
  transition: background-color 0.125s ease-in;
  margin-top: 3em;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
}

a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="https://app.nmpl.store/">
  <span>Order Now</span>
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow snippet 
In this, I have changed

```
.shop:hover>span,
.shop:focus>span,
.shop:active>span {
  color: white;
}
```

To

```
.shop:hover>a>span,
.shop:focus>a>span,
.shop:active>a>span {
  color: white;
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2em;
  color: #eff6f9;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Merriweather, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-shadow: none;
  transition: background-color 0.125s ease-in;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.wrapper{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.button a {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none
}

.button .fa-w-18 {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
}

.shop:hover>.fa-w-18,
.shop:focus>.fa-w-18,
.shop:active>.fa-w-18 {
  color: white;
}

.button:hover>a>span,
.button:focus>a>span,
.button:active>a>span {
  color: white;
}

a:focus,
.button a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button" id="bu">
    <a class="shop" href="https://app.nmpl.store/">
      <span>Order Now</span>
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```